# Smooth manifolds with a hole are homeomorphic

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm trying to prove the following result:

> Let M be a smooth connected surface and $\psi_1,\psi_2:\mathbb{D}^2\to N$ two embeddings of the unitary 2-disk. Then, $M\setminus\psi_1(\mathbb{D}^2)$ and $M\setminus\psi_2(\mathbb{D}^2)$ are homeomorphic.

Here is my attempt:

We can suppose that $\psi_1(\mathbb{D}^2)$ and $\psi_2(\mathbb{D}^2)$ are contained in two charts $(U,\varphi_1)$ and $(V,\varphi_2)$. Every smooth manifold is path-connected, so we take a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=\psi_1(0)$ and $\gamma(1)=\psi_2(0)$. Since $\gamma([0,1])$ is compact, we can cover it with a finite family $U_0=U, U_1,\ldots,U_n=V$ of chart domains. For every $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, we take a point $x_k\in\gamma([0,1])$ lying in $U_k\cap U_{k+1}$ and the image $\bar{B}_k$ by the chart homeomorphism $\varphi_k^{-1}$ of a closed ball centered in $\varphi_k(x_k)$. It suffices to show that $M\setminus\bar{B}_k$ and $M\setminus\bar{B}_{k+1}$ are homeomorphic.

We can suppose, w.l.o.g., that $\varphi_k(U_k)$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that $\varphi_k(U_k\setminus\bar{B}_k)$ and $\varphi_k(U_k\setminus\bar{B}_{k+1})$ are two open balls with a hole in $\mathbb{R}^2$. These two sets are homeomorphic (I have read that we can construct an homeomorphism using Möbius transformations of the disk). Composing with the chart homeomorphism, we have that $U_k\setminus\bar{B}_k$ and $U_k\setminus\bar{B}_{k+1}$ are homeomorphic.

Now I would like to expand the homeomorphism I have just described to $M$ but I don't know how to do it. It would be trivial if the homomorphism between the disk was the identity over the boundary, but I think it is not the case.

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be confused, but I'm not sure how to reduce to $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you are taking a euclidean neighborhood, you may need the map to be the identity outside of a compact region to guarantee the extension to $M$ is continous.

Comment: @max I'm not sure that I understand what you say. I don't need the extension to be smooth as I just want the two manifolds with hole to be homeomorphic. There was a mistake in the post: I should have written "the identity" where I wrote "constant". Maybe you are talking about that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant continuous. But yeah, generically the extension to the map you've chosen won't always exist. An approach you can take is to modify your map so it looks like the identity outside of a compact region, and then it easily extends to a map on $M$.

Comment: @max I think it would be enough that the homeomorphism between the two disks with a hole was the identity on $\mathbb{S}^1=\partial\mathbb{D}^2$ but I don’t know if such a homeomorphism exists

Answer (score 1):

The proof would follow if you could show that there exists homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^2-B(x_1,r_1)\to \mathbb{R}^2-B(x_2,r_2)$, which is the identity outside of a compact region in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We may do this in a sequence of steps.

First, we show that for any angle $\phi$ and $R>0$, there exists a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, which is a rotation by angle $\phi$ for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<R$, and is the identity for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>2R$.

Second, for $s>0$ and $R>0$, there exists a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, which is multiplication by $s$ for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<R$, and is the identity outside of a compact region.

Lastly, for $y_1,y_2\in \mathbb{R}$, there is a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(y_1)=y_2$, and such that $f$ is the identity outside of a compact region.

Letting $\phi$ denote the angle between $x_1$ and $x_2$, $s=r_2/r_1$,and $y_1=\|x_1\|$ and $y_2=\|x_2\|$, the above maps may be combined to achieve the desired homeomorphism.

The proof of all of these statements is similar. For example for the first, for any $\phi\in [0,2\pi)$ take a continous function, $\theta:\mathbb{R}_+\to [0,2\pi]$, such that $\theta(x)=\phi$ for $x<(1/2)R$ and $\theta(x)=0$ for $x>R$. Now define $f_{\phi}:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$f(x,y)=(\cos(\theta(r))x+\sin(\theta(r))y,-\sin(\theta(r))x+\cos(\theta(r))y),$$
where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain me briefly how to combine the three maps to achieve the homeomorphism?

Comment: Say the map rotating is $f_1$, the map scaling is $f_2$, and the map translating is $f_3$. Let $f_4(x,y)=(f_3(x),y)$, then $f=f_4 f_2 f_1
$